# Difficult sql about aggregate and sorting

Tags: sql, database, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I would like some help for the following question, thanks.

Original Table:

```
id, mark
1, 3
2, 4
3, 5
4, 10
5, 14
```

Result Table

```
id, mark
1, 36
2, 33
3, 29
4, 24
5, 14
```

How to use to get the result table from the original table by sql?
I have noticed that the mark field in the result table is the sum of others, but no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Using MySql DB. The sql goes well. Thanks.
I just wonder if it is still possible to get the result if the id column contains string instead of number.
For example, id: ken, Tom, Cat,....etc

Comment: Dmitry's solution will perform much better on large tables than the accepted answer (if you are using a modern DBMS).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems simple. Try this.

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       Sum(t2.mark) 
FROM   originaltable t1 
       JOIN originaltable t2 
         ON t1.id <= t2.id 
GROUP  BY t1.id 
ORDER  BY t1.id ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case to use *analytic functions* if your DBMS supports them:

```
  select id,
         sum(mark) over (order by id desc)
    from Original
```